# Copying content of a div to a new window adds extra unwanted new line

Tags: jquery, html, window

I use this code to copy contents of a div to show in a new window

```
     var w = window.open();
     var text = $("#my-div").html();
     $(w.document.body).html(text);
```

But along with the content, it adds extra new lines, around 200px before the content.

What might be the reason ?

Comment: Could you provide a snippet replicating this issue

Comment: CSS? Perhaps there's a `margin-top` or `padding-top` rule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an empty body:

```
<body>
</body>

$(document.body).html()  --> `"↵↵↵"`
```

So, if you need to avoid the empty lines use trim():

```
 var w = window.open();
 var text = $("#my-div").html().trim();
 $(w.document.body).html(text);
```

> [Trim()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim): removes whitespace from both ends of a string. Whitespace in this context is all the whitespace characters (space, tab, no-break space, etc.) and all the line terminator characters (LF, CR, etc.).